# Grails Project not compiling when I add more String variable to Domain Class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to add more String variable to my object film.

```
class Film {
    String nom, note, date //this work!!
    String description //Doesn't work :(

    static constraints={
        /*
        nom unique:true
        nom blank:false
       */
    }
}
```

There is the doom message I got for explanation :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.BatchFetchQueue.removeBatchLoadableEntityKey(BatchFetchQueue.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:388) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:671) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:254) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) [springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:51) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:103) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.doInHibernate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:198) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:142) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:112) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:253) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:179) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$save.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:165) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$1.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at film.Film.save(Film.groovy) ~[main/:na]
    at film.Film.save(Film.groovy) ~[main/:na]
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:5) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) [springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1081) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417) ~[groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:343) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:336) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:312) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62) ~[grails-web-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65) ~[grails-web-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) [springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:138) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:46) ~[grails-plugin-controllers-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:212) ~[grails-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy) ~[grails-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:49) [grails-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:254) [grails-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:243) [grails-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) [springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122) [groovy-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at wikifilm.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.BatchFetchQueue.removeBatchLoadableEntityKey(BatchFetchQueue.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:671)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.doInHibernate(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:198)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:142)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:112)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:253)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:179)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:165)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at film.Film.save(Film.groovy)
    at film.Film.save(Film.groovy)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:5)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1081)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:343)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:336)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:312)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:138)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:46)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:212)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:49)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:254)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at wikifilm.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

I tried to remove must of my other code and I didn't see any difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actualy found a solution and maybe the reason. The problem was into the filled generated while I was compiling or executing. In netbeans, you may "reload the project". It actually worked.
Thanks for trying to answear.

Comment: Please delete this question, having it here won't help anyone

Answer (score 0):

looks like the `description` is a reserved keyword in your underlying DB. Try renaming it to something like `myDescription`